# How to improve the performance when no shuffling of dataloader is needed?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, video-streaming, pytorch-dataloader

I'm currently doing some researches on video recognition. What I'm trying to do is like this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.08383).
Because it needs to sequentially read consecutive video frames (section 4.3), the dataloader will output the data like this: (the number is timestamp, and each row represents a batch)

```
[1,  9, 18, 27, 36]
[2, 10, 19, 28, 37]
[3, 11, 20, 29, 38]
[4, 12, 21, 30, 39]
...
```

The thing is, due to the sequential reading, I couldn't do shuffling for the dataloader, which unsurprisingly results in a pretty bad performance.

For such streaming loading problem, are there any tips to improve the bad performance caused by no shuffling?

I have done the following experiments to verify that the problem is really caused by no shuffling:

1. original dataloader with shuffling: good accuracy
2. original dataloader without shuffling: worst accuracy
3. the dataloader I mentioned in the question: medium accuracy but still bad

Comment: Bad performance can be caused by many reasons, have you checked out that the bad performance **does** be caused by no shuffling rather than something else?

Comment: Is this for inference or training?

Comment: Generally I think the protocol would be to make each video sequence a data example rather than each frame of a video sequence; this allows you to use a dataset/dataloader object across your different sequences without dividing the individual sequences

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/deep-learning/info